Regular hexagon inscribed in triangle
Suppose triangle $ABC$ has $\angle BAC=120^0$. How to construct a regular hexagon $PQRSTU$ inscribed in the triangle as shown. I only know that the center of the hexagon lies on the bisector $AD$. Specifically, suppose $PQRSTU$ is a cyclic hexagon as shown. $O$ is the center of the hexagon. Then, $APOQ$ is a cyclic quadrilateral since $\angle PAQ+\angle POQ=120^0+60^0=180^0$. And $OP=OQ$ so $AO$ is the bisector of angle $BAC$. However, I need to determine exactly where the center of the hexagon lies on the bisector $AD$. Can you give me some suggestions or solutions? Thank you.
(My English is not good, sorry)


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hi, @Community Bot, the question is specific enough with all necessary details given. If you can't understand it, ask someone with a natural intelligence to explain it to you instead of intimidating beginners.

You may start from a smaller hexagon.
Draw a $P_0Q_0$ segment between the triangle sides, parallel to the $BC$ side.
From $P_0$ and $Q_0$ construct missing vertices $S_0$ and $T_0$.
Then apply scaling to obtain the requested figure:
draw $AS_0$ and $AT_0$ lines and find $S$ and $T$ as their intersections with $BC$, then construct a hexagon on the $ST$ side found.
You may also use $BC$ as $P_0Q_0$.

True, but this answer doesn't address whether (and why) the center lies on the angle bisector.

@RobinSparrow That's right, but the actual question was 'how to construct a hexagon'. The OP already knows 'that the center of the hexagon lies on the bisector $AD$', so I didn't see a need to point that out. And OP didn't ask for a proof of the fact, either, so I did not bother to prove it. There also was no requirement to use the $A$ angle measure of $120^\circ$, so I skipped explaining what I did not do about it as well. Please feel free to addd a more elaborate and detailed answer if you consider it necessary.

It's the only curious/unusual part about the post - the construction is the standard one, it doesn't need any info about angles, but oddly they were given this tidbit that is only pertinent to hexagons in such triangles. Why? I don't know.

Side notes: 1/ The standard approach is to let $BC = P_0 Q_0$. Then the intersection of $AT_0, AS_0$ with $BC$ with give us $T, S$ respectively. $\quad$ 2/ That $AO$ is the angle bisector falls out of $APQO$ is cyclic (using $\angle PAQ = 120^\circ$), and so $\angle PAO = \angle QAO  = 60^\circ$. It's likely OP made this observation first, but it doesn't nail where $O$ is as yet.

@RobinSparrow: I've looked at your deleted answer, and I really like it; I'd like to suggest that you undelete it, because it helps others understand something about the problem itself (even though I really like CiaPan's solution too).

@JohnHughes: I pulled that solution because it had a problem, but a different correct solution occurred to me in the meantime, now posted.

Ah...I see. Thanks for the revised answer showing how to use the OP's known facts. I wish the revised answer were as simple as your previous one.

Here is a construct that leverages the facts from the OP that the apex angle is $120$ and the center of an inscribed hexagon must lie on that angle bisector.

Construct: 1) Bisect the angle at $A$ and find its midpoint $O$. 2) Bisect the angle at $C$ and reflect $O$ over the bisector to $O'$. 3) Draw $O'C$, where this meets the bisector of $A$ is the center of the hexagon. 4) From the center, draw the perpendicular to $BC$ and at the height where the center is midpoint, draw a line parallel to $BC$, this is the line $G''H''$.
Rationale: We can clearly inscribe a regular hexagon with a vertex at the apex, with the angle bisector (dashed line) as a diagonal to the opposite vertex, and center $O$. Consider then rotating this hexagon about $C$ by the angle at $C$ and reflecting over $BC$ to produce the same hexagon resting internal to the triangle with a side on $BC$. Plainly, a dilation from $C$ will carry this new hexagon with sides parallel to $BC$ into the desired hexagon. But the rotation at $C$ and reflection is equivalent* to a single reflection of the original hexagon about the bisector of angle $C$ (dashed line). Hence, reflecting $O$ about the bisector to $O'$ shows that the center must lie on $O'C$. So the desired center is the intersection the apex angle bisector and the line $O'C$ (the two red lines). From this center we need only construct the relevant equilateral triangles.
*: This is because the rotation can be viewed as a pair of reflections over any two lines through $C$ subtending $\frac{C}{2}$, such as the angle bisector and $BC$. But if we again reflect over $BC$ those reflections cancel to yield the single reflection over the bisector.
